# mysql check if uid record exist for today based on timestamp else do an insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to do a mysql check if a record from $uid exist from today based on $timestamp and if it doesnt then do an INSERT.

```
//EXAMPLE RECORD FROM TABLE VOTE
--- #vote_fb_uid# --- #vote_time#
     665414807        1369219044
```

tjt

```
//STEP 1 - do a look up on $uid and check with timestamp $today

        $timestamp = $this->time;
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
        $today = date('Y-m-d');

        $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM vote WHERE
        vote_fb_uid = '$this->fb_uid',
        WHERE vote_time = '$CHECK_IF_THERE_IS_AN_ENTRY_FROM_TODAY'";

        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());

//STEP 2 - If no records are found for today - then we do an INSERT

        if($no_record_for_today) {
            $sql = sprintf("
            INSERT INTO vote(
            vote_fb_uid,
            vote_time)
            VALUES ('%s','%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($this->fb_uid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($this->time));

            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
        }
```

Obviously im strugling with the SQL part for the look up - im wondering if there isnt some in-built SQL function to do this or similar?

Comment: yes it is. It's called REPLACE

Comment: what do you call "today" : last 24 hours ? same dd.mm.yyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if you had a vote in the last 24 hours :

```
SELECT * 
FROM vote 
WHERE vote_fb_uid = '$this->fb_uid'
AND   FROM_UNIXTIME(vote_time) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

if you want to limit to the same day (mean you are allowed to post at 2013.05.21 23:55 and 2013.05.22 00:05)

```
SELECT *
FROM vote
WHERE vote_fb_uid = '$this->fb_uid'
AND   DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vote_time)) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Hi Raphael - will this be within the frame of today or 24 hours from within the actual request? Atleast looking to check the frame of today

Comment: @user1231561 first version is in last 24 hours, second the same "day" (mean same values for day-month-year)

Comment: Hi Raphael - thanks for getting back to me with additional info.

Not sure why, but cant seem to get any results with your second query. I've added a record with a timestamp from now (vote_time = 1369231486) - however no results turn up - any ideas?

Comment: @user1231561 you may need FROM_UNIXTIME (thought you had a Timestamp field, not an int...). See edit

Answer (score 0):

[CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Returns the current date as a value in '`YYYY-MM-DD`' or `YYYYMMDD` format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
        -> '2008-06-13'
mysql> SELECT CURDATE() + 0;
        -> 20080613
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $today = date('Y-m-d'); //change it to timestamp if you want in timestamp
 $sql = "
        SELECT count(*) as total FROM vote WHERE
        vote_fb_uid = '$this->fb_uid' and
        vote_time = '$today'";

        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());


        if($res[0]['total'] < 1){
                $sql = sprintf("
            INSERT INTO vote(
            vote_fb_uid,
            vote_time)
            VALUES ('%s','%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($this->fb_uid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($this->time));

            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
            } else{
        //return error("custom","","Already Inserted.");    
        echo "already inserted";
    }
```

Comment: Hi Veekay - guess the SELECT count query needs to be changed to some of the above mentioned solutions - since vote_time = '$today'" or vote_time = '$timestamp'" wont really by itself check if the timestamp interval is from today?

Comment: @user1231561 yes.. if date column on database has "Y-m-d" format, then it does not need to be changed but if it has timestamp datatype, it needs to be changed..

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sql` query have a **syntax** error, you have used two times clause `WHERE` the correct *syntax* to use two or more clauses in where is using  `AND` to join them, to get only record wich don't have an entry for today you can use `DATE_SUB` with 1 day interval

```
SELECT * 
FROM vote 
WHERE vote_fb_uid = '$this->fb_uid',
AND vote_time <= DATE_SUB(vote_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```